# Best Platform for mobile development using HTML, Javascript. Apart from native app development

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, appcelerator

For Mobile App Developers

I just wanted to know about the Mobile App Development using different Platforms. Apart from `Android(Java)`, `iOS(Objective c)`. We can develop Mobile apps with the same code base for `Android` and `iPhone/iPad` using `Appcelerator`, `PhoneGap`, `jQuery Mobile`, etc...

Which one of these is good for multiple platforms(iPhone/android) app development, with Performance, with UIDesign, takes short time for development compared to native App Development ?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not a good fit for Stack Exchange. It is a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these SO links:

[Developing cross platform mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application)

[Mobile development - Native VS Cross Platform VS JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865277/mobile-development-native-vs-cross-platform-vs-javascript)

[offline HTML5 or native SDK for cross-platform app development or JQUERY mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468515/offline-html5-or-native-sdk-for-cross-platform-app-development-or-jquery-mobile)

Apart, the one which I would (personally) recommend is [Appcelerator's Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Switching to cross platform has its own pros and cons. Pros is clearly defined that its cross platform, "Write once run anywhere", but at the same time, we also loose the flexibility for the development. We have to know the drawbacks before we start with cross platform.

**Edit:** Heyy, also have a look at [Intel XDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools). This is the newest cross platform available. I found this very useful. I would say, just go for it. They say "`If you can write code in HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript*, you can use the Intel® XDK to build an HTML5 web app or a hybrid app for all of the major app stores.`" I used it for once (as i am not that good with HTML5, i've just started working with it). But its really great...